# Update Safari App Extension Content Blocker list

Tags: safari, safari-app-extension, safari-content-blocker

When creating a native content blocker from a Safari App Extension, how do I update the static JSON list after the plugin has loaded?

The only way I can see right now is to deploy a whole new version of the app which wouldn't update automatically for users.

Is it possible to update the JSON blocklist file for a content blocker from another URL without having to update the Safari App Extension through the Apple store?

Answer (score 1):

**YES** its possible you can update the JSON blocklist

**Step 1:**

Create new JSON for content blocking rules

**Step 2 :** 
Save the JSON file in Shared Container

```swift
fileprivate func saveRuleFile(ruleList:[Rule]) {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(ruleList) {

            let sharedContainerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xxx.xxxx.xxx")
            print("sharedContainerURL = \(String(describing: sharedContainerURL))")

            if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(json)
            }

            if let destinationURL = sharedContainerURL?.appendingPathComponent("Rules.json") {
                do {
                    try  encoded.write(to: destinationURL)
                } catch {
                    print (error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Step 3:** Call this method to ask the Content blocker to reload the rules

```swift
SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlocker(withIdentifier:"com.xxxx.xxx.xxxx", completionHandler: nil)
```

**Step: 4** 
Read the JSON rules file from Shared container and pass the rules to content blocker extension

```swift
func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {
        let sharedContainerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xxx.xxx.xxx")
        let sourceURL = sharedContainerURL?.appendingPathComponent("Rules.json")
        let ruleAttachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOf: sourceURL)
        let item = NSExtensionItem()
        item.attachments = ([ruleAttachment] as! [NSItemProvider])
        context.completeRequest(returningItems: [item], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Does beginRequest get called on every request? or only during Safari bootstrap?  I am trying to fetch from a server wether a domain is allowed or not and then block or allow the request. I know it's slow, but I'm just testing something out right now.

Comment: No, beginsRequest did not get called with every request, It will only get called when you will call FContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlocker(withIdentifier:"com.xxxx.xxx.xxxx", completionHandler: nil)

Comment: Followed the code, for me it works with blocking but not when unblocking. JFYI, I remove the trigger/action block from json for deactivating filter.